# SQL creating a pricing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a table that consists of prices.

Columns PriceList,ItemCode, DiscountLine,Amount,Price .

E.G.

```
*1   , ITEM1 , 0 , 100 , 0.50  
*1   , ITEM1 , 1 , 200 , 0.45  
1234 , ITEM1 , 0 , 100 , 0.45  
1234 , ITEM1 , 1 , 100 , 0.40
```

The problem is, PriceList can either be a pricelist (preceded by *) or a customer number.

I need the result in one line;

so

```
CUSTOMER    ITEM    AMOUNT0   PRICE0    AMOUNT1    PRICE1
1234        ITEM1   100       0.45      200        0.40
```

for this I am using the following code:

```
select Customer.CardCode ,Customer.CardName,SP.* from Customer inner join (
select  ItemCode,CardCode,
   max(case when DPNum=0 then Amount end) Amount1,
   max(case when DPNum=0 then Price end) Price1,
   max(case when DPNum=1 then Amount end) Amount2,
   max(case when DPNum=1 then Price end) Price2,
   max(case when DPNum=2 then Amount end) Amount3,
   max(case when DPNum=2 then Price end) Price3,
   max(case when DPNum=3 then Amount end) Amount4,
   max(case when DPNum=3 then Price end) Price4,
   max(case when DPNum=4 then Amount end) Amount5,
   max(case when DPNum=4 then Price end) Price5,
   max(case when DPNum=5 then Amount end) Amount6,
   max(case when DPNum=5 then Price end) Price6,
   max(case when DPNum=6 then Amount end) Amount7,
   max(case when DPNum=6 then Price end) Price7,
   max(case when DPNum=7 then Amount end) Amount8,
   max(case when DPNum=7 then Price end) Price8,
   max(case when DPNum=8 then Amount end) Amount9,
   max(case when DPNum=8 then Price end) Price9,
   max(case when DPNum=9 then Amount end) Amount10,
   max(case when DPNum=9 then Price end) Price10
 from SPP2 group by ItemCode,CardCode 
 ) sp
 on sp.CardCode = Customer.CardCode or sp.CardCode = '*'+cast(ListNum as varchar(1))
 where Customer.Cardcode='1234'
 order by Customer.CardCode,ItemCode,sp.CardCode DESC
```

This works apart for one small detail;
If a customer has a pricelist (and all customers do) AND they have "special" prices; I get 2 rows per item.

so My result would be:

```
CUSTOMER    NAME    ITEM    PLCODE   AMOUNT0   PRICE0    AMOUNT1    PRICE1
1234        DUMMY   ITEM1   1234     100       0.45      200        0.40
1234        DUMMY   ITEM1   *1       100       0.50      200        0.45
```

If the customer has a special price, only this should be returned.
is there any way to accomplish this in one query? (or maybe there is a more efficient way of doing what I am trying to accomplish)?

Comment: "The problem is, PriceList can either be a pricelist (preceded by *) or a customer number." - Yes, that is indeed a design error.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Unfortunately the good people at SAP made this design error.

Comment: Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to get one row per customer.  Here is the idea:

```
select csp.*
from (select c.*, sp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer
                                order by (case when plcode like '*_' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from customer c join
           (select ItemCode, CardCode,
                   max(case when DPNum=0 then Amount end) Amount1,
                   max(case when DPNum=0 then Price end) Price1,
                   . . .
            from SPP2
            group by ItemCode, CardCode 
           ) sp
           on sp.CardCode = Customer.CardCode or sp.CardCode = '*'+cast(ListNum as varchar(1))
      where c.Cardcode = '1234'
     ) csp
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Yup that's the sort of ugly inefficient query you get when you design your tables the wrong way.

Comment: Please be sure to tell that to the SAP B1 design team :) TT

Comment: With some minor tweaks I got it to work, thanks Gordon Linoff!

Comment: @tt.  . . . It may be ugly (that is a matter of opinion), but it is probably not particularly inefficient.  There is overhead for the window function when aggregating, but it is probably much less than the aggregation itself.